# How to return intersecting linestrings in boost::geometry::intersection(ring1, ring2, vector_of_linestring)?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry

I have 2 rings A and B, and I want to use `boost::geometry::intersection()` to return linestrings (the orange arrow ones):

[image: 2 rings intersection screenshot]

But my code only returns the intersecting points P1 and P2. Which part should I modify?

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/ring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/register/point.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
typedef bg::model::point<double, 2, bg::cs::cartesian> point_t;
typedef bg::model::linestring<point_t> linestring_t;
typedef bg::model::ring<point_t> ring_t;
typedef bg::model::polygon<point_t> polygon_t;

typedef bg::model::multi_point<point_t> mpoint_t;
typedef bg::model::multi_linestring<linestring_t> mlinestring_t;
typedef bg::model::multi_polygon<polygon_t> mpolygon_t;

int main() {
    point_t ptA0(0, 0);
    point_t ptA1(10, 0);
    point_t ptA2(10, 10);
    point_t ptA3(0, 10);
    ring_t ringA;
    bg::append(ringA, ptA0);
    bg::append(ringA, ptA1);
    bg::append(ringA, ptA2);
    bg::append(ringA, ptA3);
    bg::append(ringA, ptA0);
    
    point_t ptB0(5, -5);
    point_t ptB1(15, -5);
    point_t ptB2(15, 5);
    point_t ptB3(5, 5);
    ring_t ringB;
    bg::append(ringB, ptB0);
    bg::append(ringB, ptB1);
    bg::append(ringB, ptB2);
    bg::append(ringB, ptB3);
    bg::append(ringB, ptB0);  

    std::vector<linestring_t> resline;      
    bg::intersection(ringB, ringA, resline);
    for (int i = 0; i < resline.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << bg::dsv(resline[i]) << std::endl;
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the output: (10, 5) is P1 and (5, 0) is P2, which is not what I expected.

```
((10, 5), (10, 5)) 
((5, 0), (5, 0))
```

Comment: IMHO, the output is what I would have expected. I wonder that you expect something else (but you surely have your reasons). That the intersection points are expressed as 0-lenght line strings is a bit surprising to me but (at the 2nd glance) reasonable as well (due to the given output type). However, if you expect to get the intersected lines of ring B, why not the intersected lines of ring A as well?

Comment: Maybe, you could check the lines of linestring B individually against linestring A (in a loop). I'm uncertain about the performance implications but, at least, this would ensure that you get which line of linestring B intersects A...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to get a handle on this problem using just [the DE-9IM](https://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Desktop_Documentation/FME_Transformers/Transformers/spatialrelations.htm) that Boost Geometry implements: https://godbolt.org/z/KWzvzExr7 which outputs https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/9ck6gcPK5P/

```
---- void do_test(Input, Input) [with Input = boost::geometry::model::ring<boost::geometry::model::point<int, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >]
a: POLYGON((0 0,0 10,10 10,10 0,0 0))
b: POLYGON((5 -5,5 5,15 5,15 -5,5 -5))
MULTIPOINT((10 5),(5 0))
MULTIPOLYGON(((10 5,10 0,5 0,5 5,10 5)))
Segment of ringB LINESTRING(5 -5,5 5) relates to ringA 
['F', 'F', '2']
['F', 'F', '1']
['F', 'F', '2']
Segment of ringB LINESTRING(5 5,15 5) relates to ringA 
['F', 'F', '2']
['F', 'F', '1']
['F', 'F', '2']
Segment of ringB LINESTRING(15 5,15 -5) relates to ringA 
['F', 'F', '2']
['F', 'F', '1']
['F', 'F', '2']
Segment of ringB LINESTRING(15 -5,5 -5) relates to ringA 
['F', 'F', '2']
['F', 'F', '1']
['F', 'F', '2']
 ---- void do_test(Input, Input) [with Input = boost::geometry::model::linestring<boost::geometry::model::point<int, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >]
a: LINESTRING(0 0,0 10,10 10,10 0,0 0)
b: LINESTRING(5 -5,5 5,15 5,15 -5,5 -5)
MULTIPOINT((10 5),(5 0))
Segment of ringB LINESTRING(5 -5,5 5) relates to ringA 
['F', 'F', '1']
['F', 'F', 'F']
['F', 'F', '2']
Segment of ringB LINESTRING(5 5,15 5) relates to ringA 
['F', 'F', '1']
['F', 'F', 'F']
['F', 'F', '2']
Segment of ringB LINESTRING(15 5,15 -5) relates to ringA 
['F', 'F', '1']
['F', 'F', 'F']
['F', 'F', '2']
Segment of ringB LINESTRING(15 -5,5 -5) relates to ringA 
['F', 'F', '1']
['F', 'F', 'F']
['F', 'F', '2']
 ---- void do_test(Input, Input) [with Input = boost::geometry::model::polygon<boost::geometry::model::point<int, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> >]
a: POLYGON((0 0,0 10,10 10,10 0,0 0))
b: POLYGON((5 -5,5 5,15 5,15 -5,5 -5))
MULTIPOINT((10 5),(5 0))
MULTIPOLYGON(((10 5,10 0,5 0,5 5,10 5)))
Segment of ringB LINESTRING(5 -5,5 5) relates to ringA 
['F', 'F', '2']
['F', 'F', '1']
['F', 'F', '2']
Segment of ringB LINESTRING(5 5,15 5) relates to ringA 
['F', 'F', '2']
['F', 'F', '1']
['F', 'F', '2']
Segment of ringB LINESTRING(15 5,15 -5) relates to ringA 
['F', 'F', '2']
['F', 'F', '1']
['F', 'F', '2']
Segment of ringB LINESTRING(15 -5,5 -5) relates to ringA 
['F', 'F', '2']
['F', 'F', '1']
['F', 'F', '2']
```

but as far as I can see all the results are at least fully disjoint. So you might have to zoom in on the points instead of the segments:

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/eeWLCpgl6ZECOS54)**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/ring.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/iterators/segment_iterator.hpp>
#include <iostream>

namespace bg = boost::geometry;
using point_t  = bg::model::point<int, 2, bg::cs::cartesian>;
using ring_t   = bg::model::ring<point_t>;
using mpoint_t = bg::model::multi_point<point_t>;

void do_test(ring_t ringA, ring_t ringB)
{
    std::string reason;
    if (!bg::is_valid(ringA, reason)) { std::cout << "warning ringA: " << reason << "\n"; bg::correct(ringA); }
    if (!bg::is_valid(ringB, reason)) { std::cout << "warning ringB: " << reason << "\n"; bg::correct(ringB); }

    std::cout << "ringA: " << bg::wkt(ringA) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "ringB: " << bg::wkt(ringB) << std::endl;

    mpoint_t result;
    bg::intersection(ringA, ringB, result);
    std::cout << bg::wkt(result) << std::endl;

    for (auto seg : boost::make_iterator_range(bg::segments_begin(ringB),
                                               bg::segments_end(ringB))) {
        for (auto& p : result)
            if (bg::intersects(p, seg))
                std::cout << bg::wkt(p) << " intersects " << bg::wkt(seg) << "\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    do_test({{0, 0}, {0, 10}, {10, 10}, {10, 0}/*, {0, 0}*/},
            {{5, -5}, {5, 5}, {15, 5}, {15, -5}/*, {5, -5}*/});
}
```

Prints

```
warning ringA: Geometry is defined as closed but is open
warning ringB: Geometry is defined as closed but is open
ringA: POLYGON((0 0,0 10,10 10,10 0,0 0))
ringB: POLYGON((5 -5,5 5,15 5,15 -5,5 -5))
MULTIPOINT((10 5),(5 0))
POINT(5 0) intersects LINESTRING(5 -5,5 5)
POINT(10 5) intersects LINESTRING(5 5,15 5)
```